¿Hay algún problema si no invoco una ventana al usar filedialog con tkinter?
tengo una duda sobre las posibles consecuencias de usar un filedialog de tkinter sin invocar una ventana. En internet he encontrado muchas respuestas que indican que primero se tiene que invocar una ventana, aún si esta se oculta con withdraw(). Sin embargo, probé directamente usar filedialog sin invocar una ventana y también funciona, pero me pregunto si hay alguna consecuencia negativa.
Este es el código que invoca una ventana
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
ruta = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(ruta)
root. Destroy()

y este código también funciona, pero no hace la invocación de una ventana
from tkinter import filedialog

ruta = filedialog.askopenfilename()
print(ruta)

ambos códigos funcionan correctamente y generan el regreso de la ruta del archivo seleccionado en "ruta". Pero, como dije, me queda la duda de si algo negativo sucede si no invocamos (y destruimos la ventana). Uso python 3.11.8 en windows.

Tkinter siempre va a necesitar una instancia de tkinter.Tk y su mainloop ejecutandose. La segunda opción funciona porque, de no existir una ventana raiz, se crea una de forma inplícita y después se destruye. Concretamente:

askopenfilename() es una función de conveniencia del módulo tkinter.filedialog que básicamente instancia la clase del mismo módulo Open (open dialog).

La clase Open deriva de la clase _Dialog, que a su vez deriva de commondialog.Dialog.

La clase commondialog.Dialog hace esto en su inicilizador:
def __init__(self, master=None, **options):
    if master is None:
        master = options.get('parent')
    self.master = master

en esencia asigna como master el objeto asociado al argumento master o parent del inicilizador (en este orden de preferencia). Si no se especifica un padre mediante ninguno de ellos, master queda como None tras la inicilización de la clase.
Pero luego, al llamar al método show() se hace:
master = self.master
if master is None:
    master = _get_temp_root()


Por último, en _get_temp_root() tenemos:
root = Tk()
# ...
assert _default_root is None
root.withdraw()



Que es justo lo que tú haces explicitamente.
La razón por la que encuentras esos ejemplos en la web es porque esto no siempre fue asi, no hasta:
bpo-42721: Improve using simple dialogs without root window
Por lo que no debería haber problemas con ésto desde Python 3.10 en adelante. No obstante, si quieres ser explícito y crear explícitamente tu ventana raiz no hay ningun problema.

Muchas gracias por la aclaración, pensé que algo así estaría pasando, aunque no se me ocurrió ir viendo las instancias de la las que proviene la clase. Saludos :)
